# How to initialise UIDocumentPickerViewController with all type of UTIs

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, uidocumentpickervc

I want to open UIDocumentPickerViewController and It should allow user to select all type of files. I tried to mention all UTIs in UIDocumentPickerViewController init method still couldnt find valid UTIs for some of files like rar,Visio files,mpp,mpt

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:[MingleUtils allowedUTIs] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

and

```
+(NSArray*)allowedUTIs{
    return @[@"public.data",@"public.content",@"public.audiovisual-content",@"public.movie",@"public.audiovisual-content",@"public.video",@"public.audio",@"public.text",@"public.data",@"public.zip-archive",@"com.pkware.zip-archive",@"public.composite-content",@"public.text"];
}
```

Answer (score 33):

If you want to allow any file type, you should use

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController* documentPicker = 
  [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.data"]
                                                         inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

See apple docs for [UTI concepts](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html)

Comment: custom extension are not supported in "public.data"

Comment: On iOS 12.0 - No crash but also does not allow me to select the files I want.

Answer (score 13):

Swift 5:

```
import MobileCoreServices

    let importMenu = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.item"], in: .import)
    importMenu.delegate = self
    importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: If you are using delegate in your reply, please add the initializers to the code in the reply.

Comment: You could also use `[UTType.item]`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot is to use [abstract UTI types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MobileCoreServices/Reference/UTTypeRef/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/UTI_Abstract_Types).

Using kUTTypeContent and kUTTypeItem should cover most of the file types.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController* documentPicker = 
  [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.item"]
                                                         inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

Comment: Results in assertion error: Passed in type public.item doesn't conform to either public.content or public.data. If you are exporting a new type, please ensure that it conforms to an appropriate parent type. @"public.data" is correct.