# Converting a code from Swift to Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I started developing apps using Swift directly so i have little to know idea about Objective C, however i had to take up a project which was implemented in Objective C and fix few bugs.

I came across a code in Swift which i want to convert to Objective C

```
func mySpecialFunction(){

let importMenu = UIDocumentMenuViewController(documentTypes: [String(kUTTypePDF)], in: .import)
            importMenu.delegate = self
            importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet       
            self.present(importMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Now i have done some research and got this

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu = *Code Here* ;
importMenu.delegate = self;
importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:importMenu animated:YES];
```

Can anyone help me how to can i get the first line converted to Objective C in the code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to initialise UIDocumentPickerViewController with all type of UTIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099775/how-to-initialise-uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-with-all-type-of-utis)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this.

```
 UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeContent] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.item", (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeContent, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeData, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypePackage, (__bridge NSString *) kUTTypeDiskImage, @"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
```

Use Above Code